# PHP Ternary operator clarification

Tags: php, operators, ternary-operator

I use the ternary operator quite often but I've not been able to find anything in the documentation about this and I've always wondered it.

The following is a possible example:

```
echo ($something->message ? $something->message : 'no message');
```

as you can see, if $something->message is correct, we return $something->message, but why write it twice? Is there a way to do something like:

```
echo ($something->message ? this : 'no message');
```

Now I'm not well versed in programming theory, so it's possible that there is a reason that the former cannot be referenced with something *like* "this" but why not? Would this not stream line the use of the ternary operator? For something like my example it's pretty useless, but let's say it's

```
echo (function(another_function($variable)) ? function(another_function($variable)) : 'false');
```

I'm unable to find *any* way to do this, so I'm assuming it's not possible, if I'm wrong please inform me, otherwise: why not? Why is this not possible, what's the technical reason, or is it just something that never happened? Should I be declaring it as a variable and then testing against that variable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PHP have a default assignment idiom like perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2958630/does-php-have-a-default-assignment-idiom-like-perl)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1 evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

[Source](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary)

**For example**

```
$used_value = function1() ?: $default_value;
```

**Is the same as**

```
$check_value = function1(); //doesn't re-evaluate function1()
if( $check_value ) {
    $used_value = $check_value;
} else {
    $used_value = $default_value;
}
```

**Word for the wise**

If your going to be depending on typecasting to `TRUE` it's important to understand what WILL typecast to `TRUE` and what won't. It's probably worth brushing up on PHP's [type juggling](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) and reading the [type conversion tables](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php). For example `(bool)array()` is `FALSE`.

Comment: Whoever submitted that patch is my hero. I was just reading that page and seemingly skipped straight over that part. Thanks, maybe I should upgrade then. I'll accept your answer when the time limit is up!

Comment: `echo ($something->message ? : 'no message');` in the case of the OP's first example.

Comment: +1 Leave it to php to surprise you with an obscure implementation of the ternary operator of all things :) gotta love the incongruities..

Comment: @Kendall wow... :) Well most of my colleagues get grouchy when they see a ternary operator. I'd *love* to have them try to figure out one of these ternary variants :)

Comment: The funny thing is that this was the result of the PHP 6 brainstorming about ifsetor() (see http://www.php.net/~derick/meeting-notes.html#ifsetor-as-replacement-for-foo-isset-foo-foo-something-else), and while it's a neat feature, it doesn't actually solve the original problem, since $_GET['foo'] ?: '' will still throw an notice if it's not set.