# More elegant PHP code

Tags: php

Assuming that the method setEmail1() sets the email address or generates error messages if the email address seems to be wrong, is there a more elegant way, maybe in only 1 line, to do the following ? :

```
    $email2 = $newCustomer->setEmail1($_SESSION['customer_new']['email2']); 
    if ($email2 !== true) $_SESSION['customer_new']['error']['email2'] = $email2;
```

Thank You !

Comment: one-liner => ternary operator => http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Ternary operator clarification](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580461/php-ternary-operator-clarification)

Answer (score 1):

There are examples set out below, but for clarity and readability they are not usually advised. Its what you asked for of course so those are the answers but I would seriously reconsider doing that. If you have to debug the code those one liners can be a pain the nether regions.

Personally I would be looking at something like this, its basic classes no pattern involved but you may want to look into class pattern such as MVC or the factory pattern to make your coding more standardised.

**class.email.php**

```
class email {

    public function validateEmail($email_address) {

        // add your validation here. format it in a readable
        // manner and debugging/future updates will be a breeze.

    return $result;

    }

}
```

**file.php**

```
require_once('class.email.php');

// With a framework like MVC this would have been preloaded in
// the controller, but we initialise it here.
$class_obj = NEW email();

// and here is the one liner that you would see in your main file.
$email = $class_obj->validateEmail($email);
```

Comment: My class already validates the email and if the adress is wrong the method setEmail1() returns error messages that are stored in $_SESSION['customer_new']['error']['email2'] ;-)

Comment: Then you are already separating the logic from the functionality. I don't see any need for short hand when they just make the code less manageable.

Answer (score 0):

You could do the following. But why do you wanna write all in one line?

```
$_SESSION['customer_new']['error']['email2'] = ($newCustomer->setEmail1($_SESSION['customer_new']['email2']) !== true) ? $email2 : null;
```

Comment: This does not work for me :-( , since in my case the session variable should contain error messages generated by the class method or should not to be set at all (not set to null).

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['customer_new']['error']['email2'] = $newCustomer->setEmail1($_SESSION['customer_new']['email2']) ?: null;
```

The ?: operator is a variant of the ternary operator :)

```
$x = $y ?: 0;
// is equivalent to
$x = $y ? $y : 0;
```

Comment: This does not work for me, since in my case the session variable should contain error messages generated by the class method or should not to be set at all (not set to null).

Comment: If you want it not set at all, then there is no other way than what you did in the original post. But if you use isset() on a null value, you get the same result as if it's not defined. isset() is also faster than array_key_exists()