# Using ?: shorthand in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, ternary-operator

I have a login function that i am using to login users using telephone numbers. I am getting the phone numbers from the user and then using the phone number to fetch the matching email address.

For that i have this code

```
public function processLogin(Request $request){
    $phone = $request->get('phone');
    $getEmail = User::where('users_telephone_number', '=',$phone )->first()->email;
    $email = $getEmail;
    $password = $request->get('password');
    //echo $email.$password;
    $data = array(
        'email' => $email,
        'password' => $password
        );

    if (Auth::attempt($data,true)) {
```

When the number is wrong, i get this error

`Trying to get property of non-object`

To solve the problem i want to have the variable `$getEmail` to be equal to  `none@dont.com` which will fail well like all other wrong email and password combos.

How can i make sure i catch errors in this one line i am using to fetch the email

`User::where('users_telephone_number', '=',$phone )->first()->email;`

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3580461/php-ternary-operator-clarification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the $user first, then access the email.

```
$user = User::where('users_telephone_number', '=',$phone )->first();
$email = isset($user) ? $user->email : 'default string';
```

Answer (score 1):

You are imediatly trying to get the email property of an object you're trying to fetch.
I would suggest using the method `findOrFail`, when there is no result found a `NotFoundException` will be thrown, which will return a `404 not found`.

Overall it will look like this:

```
$user = User::where('users_telephone_number', '=',$phone )->findOrFail();
$email = $user->email;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$phone = $request->get('phone');
$getEmail = User::where('users_telephone_number', '=',$phone )->first();
$email = $getEmail ? $getEmail->email : null;
if(!$email)
    return abort(400);
```

Answer (score 0):

Or testing null:

```
$user = User::where('users_telephone_number', '=',$phone )->first();
$email = $user ? $user->email : 'default string';
```

If your query doesn't return any `User` instance, it will return a default null value.

Or... you could test the email

```
$password = $request->get('password');
$user = User::where('users_telephone_number', '=', $phone)->whereNotNull('email')->first();

if ($user && Auth::attempt([$user->email, $password], true)) {
    ...
}
```