# Default value on insert PHP and SQL

Tags: php, sql

I want to make that when someone inserts a post into my database that if they don't supply their name it defaults to anonymous. How would I do this? 
My code here

```php
$query =  "INSERT INTO cinemaPost (name, text, likes, reply_to) VALUES (?, ?, 0, NULL)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
$stmt->bindValue(1, $post_data['name']);
$stmt->bindValue(2, $post_data['post']);

$stmt->execute();
```

I have tried doing a default in the create tables for the db but when the user triggers the insert it overides it as a blank field.

```sql
CREATE TABLE CinemaPost(
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
  name varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT 'anonymous',
  text varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  post_date timestamp(6) NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6) ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(6),
  likes INT NOT NULL,
  reply_to INT,
  Primary KEY (id)
);
```

Comment: what RDBMS are you using?

Comment: What's the exact problem? Why not check whether the field containing the name is empty (by whatever terms you define)?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44717227/2943403 , https://stackoverflow.com/a/6459214/2943403

Answer (score 2):

The default value will only be used if you don't actually insert to the column i.e. you would need to remove `name` from the `INSERT` column list. For example:

```
if (empty($post_data['name'])) {
    $query =  "INSERT INTO cinemaPost (text, likes, reply_to) VALUES (?, 0, NULL)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $post_data['post']);
}
else {
    $query =  "INSERT INTO cinemaPost (name, text, likes, reply_to) VALUES (?, ?, 0, NULL)";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($query);
    $stmt->bindValue(1, $post_data['name']);
    $stmt->bindValue(2, $post_data['post']);
}
```

It's probably simplest just to check the input value and replace it with `"anonymous"` if it's empty instead:

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, empty($post_data['name']) ? 'anonymous' : $post_data['name']);
```

Comment: Is this question perhaps a duplicate on Stack Overflow, Nick?  You don't need rep anymore.  Please help the team by closing close-able question instead of answering.

Comment: @mickmackusa the only one of those which could be considered to be a duplicate - because it relates to setting a default value in the database - is the first and the answer to that has 2 (of the 3) parts of it which are incorrect (using `isset` or `??`). Additionally that question puts values directly into the query where this one uses a prepared statement. And the answer to that question does not explain why the default value in the table does not get used.

Comment: Adjusted the duplicates to show your two techniques demonstrated by the highest voted answer on respective pages.  `empty()` might not be a good call for silly-fringe cases. https://3v4l.org/rKSTW

Answer (score 0):

Using `DEFAULT` on the SQL side is absolutely correct. However, you need to ensure that value is actually used.

The default value is only used if you pass `NULL` as the parameter from PHP. An empty string (`""`) is not `NULL`.

```
$stmt->bindValue(1, empty($post_data['name']) ? NULL : $post_data['name']);
```