# can this conditional logic work in PHP?

Tags: php, if-statement

I came across some code today where a string is compared to two values at the same time.  I've never seen this before - will this work? Can someone explain it to me?

```
$foo = 'date';

if ($foo == ('date' || 'datetime')) {
  echo "Hello world";
}
```

Comment: I do hope the coder who wrote this wasn't employed by anyone ;-)

Comment: I don't know what the author of this code was sniffing, but I sure want to know where I can buy it. ;-)

Comment: See also: [Does PHP have a default assignment idiom like perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2958630/90527)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That won't work. Write `if ($foo == 'date' || $foo == 'datetime')`.

Not only won't `||` work for selecting from a set, but also you <strike>use</strike> used a single `=`, which is for assignment rather than comparison.

In this case, the constant strings are compared using the boolean or operator. To do that, they are both converted to boolean. Since they are non-empty strings, they evaluate to `true`. true or true returns true, <strike>which is assigned to `$foo`</strike> which is compared to $foo. That comparison will always be true if $foo is 'date' or 'datetime' or about any other non-empty string.

So, whatever the previous value of $foo was, or even if it wasn't assigned at all, the if-expression always evaluates to true, so you always get the echo, and $foo will always be `true` afterwards.

Comment: sorry - in my haste, I forgot to add two =, I'll fix that.

Comment: Well, technically that DOES work, it just doesn't do what whoever wrote it meant it to do. `"date" || "datetime"` simply gets evaluated to 1, so the condition is always true (also, using the `=` instead of `==` would also make the condition always true).

Comment: @nico. Sure, it does. The code runs fine. See my explanation of what actually happens.

Comment: @veilig. You do know that you can copy code instead of typeing it over. I always wonder how there can be typos in such a question. ;)

Answer (score 3):

This'll not work. `('date' || 'datetime')` always evaluates to `true`.

Use this instead:

```
$foo = 'date';

if ($foo == 'date' || $foo == 'datetime') {
  echo "Hello world";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try the following:

```
$haystack = array("date","datetime");
$needle = "date";

if (in_array($needle,$haystack)) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

No. the `||` or `OR` operators only work with Booleans. you'll need this condition:

```
if ($foo == 'date' || $foo == 'datetime') { ... }
```

---

But what if you have 10 possible values? You'll need one for each? yes and no.

Another possibility is to insert all the possible values into an **array** and check whether your value is possible by comparing it to that array, using `in_array()`:

```
$possible_values = array('date', 'datetime');
if (in_array($foo, $possible_values)) { ... }
```