# PHP alternative to ternary operator

Tags: php, javascript, ternary-operator

In JavaScript you can use the following code:

```
var = value || default;
```

Is there an equivalent in PHP except for the ternary operator:

```
$var = ($value) ? $value : $default;
```

The difference being only having to write `$value` once?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does PHP have a default assignment idiom like perl?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2958630/90527), [PHP Ternary operator clarification](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3580461/), [How to set default value to a string in PHP if another string is empty?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/6459171/90527)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PHP short-ternary ("Elvis") operator vs null coalescing operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34571330/php-short-ternary-elvis-operator-vs-null-coalescing-operator)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Since of php 5.3
`$var = $value ?: $default`

Comment: Thanks, only issue is that Dreamweaver doesn't recognize this as valid code so I'm left with an error on that line. The PHP processor does, so I suppose that's what counts...

Answer (score 5):

```
$var = $value or $var = $default;
```

Answer (score 1):

Another fiddly workaround (compatible with pre-5.3) would be:

```
$var = current(array_filter(array($value, $default, $default2)));
```

But that's really just advisable if you do have multiple possible values or defaults. (Doesn't really save on typing, not a compact syntax alternative, just avoids mentioning `$value` twice.)

Comment: Thanks, essentially I was looking for a way to save on typing (and to add a little more readability)

Answer (score 0):

with 5.3 or without 5.3 I would write.

```
$var = 'default';
if ($value) $var = $value;
```

because I hate write-only constructs.